# How can I get multiple elements and print in Robot Framework- SeleniumLibrary?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, robotframework-ide

```
${get_t}=    Get Text    //h6[@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-subtitle2']
Log    ${get_t}
${get_t1}=    Get Element Count    xpath://h6[@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-subtitle2']
Log    ${get_t1}
${get_t3}=    Get WebElements    xpath://h6[@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-subtitle2']
Log    ${get_t3}
```

when I get Count it shows the count but when i print it using **Get WebElements** it doens't print the text. If I give **Get Text** it print the first text alone.

[image]

**Xpath**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you want to achieve - get/print the text of each element? Because `Get Webelements` does just what its name says - returns you a list of matching elements - selenium element objects. 
Having that, if you want to print the text of each one, just iterate over the list and call `Get Text` on each member:

```
FOR    ${el}    IN    @{get_t3}
    ${txt}=    Get Text    ${el}
    Log    ${txt}
END
```

Comment: First of all thanks. I want to get all elements of the xpath and print it. With your code i tried doing it and "@{get_t3}" this is xpath rite ?? . When I tried it still print the first value
    : FOR    ${el}    IN    xpath://h6[@class='MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-subtitle2']
    \    ${txt}=    Get Text    ${el}
    \    Log    ${txt}

Comment: Actually no, `@{get_t3}` is a list object, not an xpath. It is the result of this call - `${get_t3}=    Get WebElements    xpath://h6[@class='MuiTypography... `, and the loop iterates over each of its elements - e.g. each cycle works with a different element, until going through all of them. What you are doing in your comment is iterating over a single string - and thus getting only a single text from the page.

Comment: We need to convert to string from web element when we iterate and print?

Comment: A web element is just that - a selenium reference to an object in the page DOM. In other words, it's a pointer to an element - a `div`, `a`, or another one. You can do various things with it - click, change it or get a property - like its text. So with that web element in hand, calling `Get Text` returns you the text it encompasses.